# Having problem after adding Lexical Rich Text editor in payload cms

Tags: reactjs, rich-text-editor, payload, lexicaljs, payload-cms

I am new to payload cms and was told to change the text editor because it was a bit complicated (slate editor). Then I found out about Lexical Rich Text editor and tried to implement it as shown in docs here https://payloadcms.com/docs/rich-text/lexical.

I added the editor generated graphql schemas and generated types and the editor also renders on the admin page but I cannot view it gives this error.

[image]

I have changed payload.config.ts and added

```
import { lexicalEditor } from '@payloadcms/richtext-lexical'
```

instead of slate editor. Please can someone help me thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to render rich text that was created by the Slate editor?  See https://payloadcms.com/docs/rich-text/lexical#migrating-from-slate

Have you modified the component in your frontend to render lexical rich text? See https://payloadcms.com/docs/rich-text/lexical#lexical-html